# Mocking function of Django default method parameter with unittest-mock

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

I am trying to mock the infamous `datetime.now()` function so that I have a frozen date easy to test in my unit test. I usually use [unittest-mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) package to do so, patching the `datetime` object of the interested module.

The problem is that the `datetime.now()` I am trying to patch is coming from a default function parameter, as follows (in `views.py`):

```
def user_as_guest(user_id,
                  date=datetime.now()):
```

So this simply doesn't work (`test.py`):

```
    with patch('myapp.views.datetime') as mock_date:
        frozen_date = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
        mock_date.now.return_value = frozen_date

        Events.user_as_guest(user_id_1)
```

Even if debugging the flow I can see the `datetime.now()` is correctly patched, I imagine the callable object used for assigning the default parameter has a different scope from the module, but I can't go further. Thank for your help!

#### Side Note

I realized the code I wrote was not doing *exactly* what I wanted. I thought the default function parameters were evaluated and *late bound*, that is not actually the case.

Indeed, my date object would contain a date *in the past*, not the one at the time of the function call. This explains more why I couldn't patch it with my approach.

I fixed everything assigning the date in the function body, so the old but gold mocking approach works. But still, the question is valid...